# How to get a half edge implementation that is sane?

Tags: data-structures, rust, geometry, unsafe

I have been fighting the borrow checker and undefined behavior for days now and I am frustrated.

There is a data structure called a half edge (also known as a doubly connected edge list), if you do not know what that is please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7s7pCPNojs) or see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) to understand what this is about.

I have implemented this multiple times in C++, in that language I use the following interface:

```
edge.next()

face.edge()

vert.edge()
```

and so on, to access elements. note 2 things. 1 you are accessing elements through the facets, not the mesh, 2 no explicit referencing to the enclosing mesh data structure exists.

This is the ideal interface, it;s simple, it's readable. The following are other potential interfaces that I abhor, they are stupid, cumbersome, terrible and no sane human should be subjected to them:

```
mesh.hedges[edge_id]
mesh.get_edge(edge_id)
```

Why? well let's say you wanted to do `edge.next().next().next()` with the above. We would get:

```
 mesh.get_edge(mesh.get_edge(mesh.get_edge(id).next_id).next_id)
```

Clearly unreadable, to make it work it would need to be:

```
id1 = mesh.get_edge(id).next_id
id2 = mesh.get_edge(id1).next_id
mesh.get_edge(id2)
```

This is at least readable, but we achieved in 3 lines and a whole bunch of characters something that could be achieved in a one liner. There's also way more thinking involved, it taxes the brain of the user. We consider the users brain to be a valuable resource that should never be burdened with nonsense.

With this in min, I tried using unsafe code to make something like this work:

```rust
pub struct HEdge<'a, V, E, F>
where
    V: Clone,
    E: Clone,
    F: Clone,
{
    pub(crate) id: GeomId,

    pub(crate) next_id: GeomId,
    pub(crate) prev_id: GeomId,
    pub(crate) pair_id: GeomId,

    pub(crate) vert_id: GeomId,

    pub(crate) face_id: GeomId,

    pub data: E,

    pub(crate) mesh: *mut HalfMesh<'a, V, E, F>,
}

impl<'a, V, E, F> HEdge<'a, V, E, F>
where
    V: Clone,
    E: Clone,
    F: Clone,
{
     pub fn next_mut(&self) -> &mut HEdge<'a, V, E, F>
    {
        unsafe {
            debug_assert!(self.next_id != ABSENT);
            debug_assert!(usize::from(self.next_id) < (*self.mesh).hedges.len());

            &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[usize::from(self.next_id)]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an example usage (that segfaults):

```rust
pub fn split(&mut self) -> &mut Vert<'a, V, E, F>
    {
        unsafe {
            let v2_id = self.pair().prev().source().id;
            let v3_id = self.dest().id;
            let v4_id = self.prev().source().id;

            let vn_id = (*self.mesh).add_vert(self.source().data.clone());

            let e1_id = self.id;
            let e2_id = self.pair().id;
            let e3_id = self.next().id;
            let e4_id = self.prev().id;
            let e5_id = self.pair().next().id;
            let e6_id = self.pair().prev().id;

            let (e7_id, e8_id) =
                (*self.mesh).add_edge(vn_id, v2_id, self.data.clone(), self.data.clone());
            let (e9_id, e10_id) =
                (*self.mesh).add_edge(v4_id, vn_id, self.data.clone(), self.data.clone());
            println!("{}", (*self.mesh).hedges.len());
            let (e11_id, e12_id) =
                (*self.mesh).add_edge(v3_id, vn_id, self.data.clone(), self.data.clone());

            let f1_id = self.face_id;
            let f2_id = self.pair().face_id;
            let f3_id = (*self.mesh).add_face(e10_id, self.face().data.clone());
            let f4_id = (*self.mesh).add_face(e8_id, self.pair().face().data.clone());

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f1_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e1_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e3_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e9_id.0 as usize],
            );

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f2_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e2_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e7_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e6_id.0 as usize],
            );

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f3_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e10_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e4_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e11_id.0 as usize],
            );

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f4_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e8_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e12_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e5_id.0 as usize],
            );

            return &mut (*self.mesh).verts[vn_id.0 as usize];
        }
```

Well this design is utterly broken. It triggers UB left and right, it doesn't work, it;s bad, it's terrible.

I have scouted the internet, tried multiple hacks and different things. I cannot, for the life of me, find a way to get rust working the way this api works in C++, that is, to get

`edge.next()` as a method with no UB, segfaults or compilation errors.

Every suggestion people give me results in basically `mesh.get_edge(id)`, which we established is bad.

This code was an attempt at adapting some C++ code that has been battle tested for 3 years that provides that API. How do I achieve this in rust? i.e. how do I make a `struct Mesh` and `struct Edge`, such that edge references mesh under the hood and allows me to do edge.next() without UB or runtime errors?

For further context and the curious this is the [implementation](https://gitlab.com/Makogan/neverengine/-/tree/master/crates/hedge/src) atm, but as mentioned this is a broken design.

Comment: Have you read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)?

Comment: This question feels to unfocused for a good StackOverflow question, but it can be fixed. I would remove all mention of API design and instead focus on the API you *want* (which segfaults) and present that in the question. Then, all relevant code should be in the post so you should *reduce* your problem into a minimal example that reproduces the issue and show only that. It would also be helpful if you included a link to the C++ library you are trying to copy. With that, you will hopefully get a quick answer that addresses the heart of your problem.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I feel that one reason for the issue here is that your data structure has a lot of invariants to maintain. You are trying to create an "ergonomic" API that provides simple operations that break the invariant. This can be seen by the fact that you need a special `ABSENT` geometry id. Don't do that. Each public API should preserve the invariants. So for example `attach_face` should not be exist, or not be public, while `split` should. Structure invariants should only be broken within your methods, and always restored before returning.

Comment: Then, inside your methods, you can use un-ergonomic low-level operations, while provide "ergonomic" invariant-safe accessors for users of your module. Also, you probably don't need `RefCell`s. Use the borrow checker. Have mutable and immutable versions of your "mesh reference + item id" structures. Only one mutable one can be kept at any time and used to perform mutable operations.